Inter AKS communication not working with Allow only Virtual Network communication
I'm trying to enable inter AKS communication between pods of different clusters in same Virtual Network but I don't want to expose AKS/VNet to the internet.
Here's what I tried

I created a new AKS cluster in the same VNet, same NSG as old AKS cluster but different SubNets. The old AKS cluster has a health service deployed. I can see that both new and old AKS clusters are part of same VNet but different subnets.
I created a NSG rule that allows connections within VirtualNetwork and drop rest of the connections
I logged into one of the AKS nodes using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-access
But when I try to do wget health service (wget https://domain/health), it only works from old AKS cluster where the health service is deployed and not from new AKS cluster
It works when I add a NSG rule to allow 443 communications over internet. But doesn't work without the public NSG rule. It seems like the VirtualNetwork rule is being ignored and

I'm kinda lost in what looks like a very simple problem statement. I tried to use tools like network watcher but couldn't reach to any conclusion on what might be causing the issue.

Can you provide your vnet/subnet ranges, your service CIDR and the CNI you are using ?
My expectation is that you can't access pod ranges because the service tag VirtualNetwork doesn't contains your pod CIDR.
You can also try to assign a static private IP to your service by adding 2 annotations :
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
annotations:
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: true
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-ipv4: 10.x.x.x <-- This should be an available ip in the corresponding aks subnet. 
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: myport
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

Then on the other AKS try to call your api :
kubectl run -it --rm --image=curlimages/curl curly -- curl http://10.x.x.x/health


Here's how the masked ranges looks like
Service CIDR: 192.168.0.0/16
SubNet 1: 192.168.7.0/24
SubNet 2: 192.168.8.0/24
Default: 192.168.255.0/24
VNet Range: 192.168.0.0/16
CNI: Old (kubenet), new (Azure CNI)

how to check if the pod ranges is not part of service tag VirtualNetwork. I tried adding public private IPs of the AKS nodes to NSG and that didn't work too. Only thing that worked is Internet based rule

also, I'm using domain ((wget https://domain/health) to make the call. Can that be an issue? It does resolve the public IP of the old AKS cluster where the health service is deployed. Are you suggesting that this call should happen over private IP?

You can use public access to allow inter communication but its counterproductive, these network request should be in private network using VNet.
As said on my post, give your service a private IP on the AKS subnet and configure applications that use this service using the private IP you give to your service.
In your case its totally normal that you need to enable internet access to enable AKS interconnection but its not the best solution.

For internet access consider using Azure Application Gateway for Containers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/for-containers/overview
